# customize a field in automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

```
public string AdjustTimezoneForDisplay(DateTime date)
{
    //.......
}
```

automapper config

```
Mapper.Initialize(config =>
{
     config.CreateMap<EquipmentOther, KMEquipmentOthers>()
               .ForMember(x=>x.Status,opt=>opt.Ignore())
               .ForMember(x => x.CreatedOn, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>src.CreatedOn));
}
```

what am trying to achieve is to adjust time zone for CreatedOn field like the below code

```
ObjKMEquipmentOthers.CreatedOn = this._Utility.AdjustTimezoneForDisplay(EquipmentOtherDetails.CreatedOn);
```

would anybody please help me to achieve this

ps:AdjustTimezoneForDisplay is function to adjust time zone and return with local time

Comment: `.ForMember(x => x.CreatedOn, opt => opt.MapFrom(this._Utility.AdjustTimezoneForDisplay(opt.CreatedOn)))`

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh expression is not vaild, opt.MapFrom(opt.CreatedOn) second opt doesnot contains CreatedOn

Comment: .ForMember(x => x.CreatedOn, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => AdjustTimezoneForDisplay(x.CreatedOn))); this is working when i changed static class to non static

Comment: is there any way to call it in static class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me ,hope this will help anybody in future

```
.ForMember(x => x.CreatedOn, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => AdjustTimezoneForDisplay(x.CreatedOn)));
```

and ps : AdjustTimezoneForDisplay must be static one .(initialy it was non static this is my problem ),again mapping initilizer  also be static

```
public static string AdjustTimezoneForDisplay(DateTime date)
{
 //.......
}
public static void RegisterMaps()
{
  Mapper.Initialize(config =>
  {
   config.CreateMap<EquipmentOther, KMEquipmentOthers>()
           .ForMember(x=>x.Status,opt=>opt.Ignore())
           .ForMember(x => x.CreatedOn, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => AdjustTimezoneForDisplay(x.CreatedOn)));
  }
}
```